# Syntax errors returned when attempting to use GO inside sp_MSforeachDB, NULL errors returned when attempting to remove it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to develop a script which, when run, will drop all users beginning with the prefix "COMPANY\" that do not belong to a list of pre-authorized users. This script will be run to periodically sweep the servers of former employee DB user accounts. For testing purposes, the script below only prints the name of the unauthorized users, instead of dropping them. I need to do this for each DB on the server instance, so I am using sp_MSforeachDB. However, when I run the script, I get multiple errors, all with the same message:

```
Error in this script.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 57
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

When I attempt to run the script outside of sp_MSforeachDB, the script works fine. So, it is obvious to me that the issue is with executing the GO statement inside sp_MSforeachDB.

I found in another post that GO is not a T-SQL command and that is why it is throwing this error when it is inside sp_MSforeachDB, but if I attempt to remove GO, several NULL errors are returned to me instead of the error above:

```
Error in this script.
Msg 50000, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
Error Number: (null), Severity: (null), State: (null), Line: (null), 
(null)
```

This error is also returned if I run the GO-less statement normally (not inside sp_MSforeachDB). If I remove all error handling in the script, it works fine, but I do need to have error handling in this script.

So...I'm a bit lost as to how to make this work. Admittedly, I am pretty new to error handling in T-SQL and was working off of an example, so there may be something obvious I am missing. Ideas? Are there good alternatives to sp_MSforeachDB that don't use stored procedures at all which would work with this? Any and all help is appreciated.

Script is below. You can remove GOTO BAGIT and BAGIT: GO to see the NULL errors.

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb
'USE [?];

/* Declare error-handling variables */

DECLARE @err_no int, @err_severity int, @err_state int, @err_line int, @err_message varchar(4000)
DECLARE @nrows int

/* First pull in list of users who have a COMPANY user name but are not in list of approved users */

DECLARE @Fetch_UsersList_Status INT;
DECLARE @ExecuteSQL_UsersList VARCHAR(2500);
DECLARE @NextUser VARCHAR(250);

DECLARE UsersList CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals
    where
    name LIKE ''COMPANY\%''
    AND
    name NOT IN (''COMPANY\User1'',''COMPANY\User2'',''COMPANY\User3'',''COMPANY\User4'',''COMPANY\User5'')

OPEN UsersList
FETCH NEXT FROM UsersList INTO @NextUser

/* Use local variable to store UsersList FETCH_STATUS. This will be used as the condition for the USERDROP WHILE loop */

SET @Fetch_UsersList_Status = @@FETCH_STATUS

/* USERDROP WHILE Loop */
BEGIN TRY
WHILE @Fetch_UsersList_Status = 0
    BEGIN
            PRINT @NextUser
            FETCH NEXT FROM UsersList INTO @NextUser
            SET @Fetch_UsersList_Status = @@FETCH_STATUS    
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT @err_no=ERROR_NUMBER(), @err_severity=ERROR_SEVERITY(), @err_state=ERROR_STATE(),
            @err_line=ERROR_LINE(), @err_message=ERROR_MESSAGE()
            GOTO ERROR_EXIT
END CATCH
CLOSE UsersList
DEALLOCATE UsersList

GOTO BAGIT

ERROR_EXIT:
  DECLARE @newline char(1)
  SET @newline = CHAR(10)
  PRINT ''Error in this script.''
  RAISERROR(''Error Number: %d, Severity: %d, State: %d, Line: %d, %s%s'', 15, 1,
            @err_no, @err_severity, @err_state, @err_line, @newline, @err_message) WITH LOG

BAGIT:

GO

'
```

Comment: Works for me when I remove the bottom GO.  Looks like the GOTO works fine

Comment: I'm curious though, why not just create a temp table, run a very simple and short sp_foreachdb to gather the names, then run another script to log and drop who you want.  No cursors required.

Comment: GO separate batches in SQL. You can also use it to run things multiple times like GO 4. You should have it outside your last quote mark in this case, since your batch includes EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb. The GO inside of the sql statement is  trying to execute a command internally / nested from the procedure which is calling it.

Comment: @paulbarbin: Because I haven't had enough coffee yet...that's a great suggestion, thanks. :)

Comment: @paulbarbin: I'm still having issues with this script and I think I found out why when I went to replace the `PRINT @NextUser` line with the real deal line:

`SET @ExecuteSQL_UsersList =''DROP User ['' + @NextUser + ''];''
EXEC(@ExecuteSQL_UsersList)`

There's something EXEC() doesn't like about how I'm setting @ExecuteSQL_UsersList, but from all the examples I've looked at, I cannot figure out why. I did the exact same type of thing in another script I worked on and it didn't raise this issue.

Comment: I'm having trouble posting comments and answers to the site.  Not sure what the problem is.  I'll keep trying.  It seems to be ok with text but not with code...